# Multiple Plugin best practice in Multisite

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I am writing several bespoke plugins for a client running a multisite installation. They want separate plugins, but there will be some overlap. For example, the emails need to all go out through the same queueing system, errors need to be recorded in the same way.

I am considering having a core plugin which will include this functionality and also enqueue standard styles.

Is this approach frowned upon? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Seems sensible to me. What's the client's motivation? The main issue I can think of is if they'd rather deploy new code to sites one at a time to e.g. test new code on the smaller, less important site first and using common code would break that workflow - but then if that was the case they probably wouldn't want multisite.

Comment: Consider to have specialized, per-site plugins, and global ones.